# Bad json array Python post request to PHP

Tags: php, python, arrays, json

I'm trying to send a post request with Python to PHP (I'm using Phalcon PHP).

Python Code:

```
array_hash =["0x348eb29f3295fedc10b5b869c751fb5479585c7e65169512c3a5ff474bc0e85a", "0x63b2590119f7ea533ed93e6b2e6112410fbf49f99157bc6d7e0ce7469d3d23a8", "0xfbcdc555a3783b5cfa495ad7a5d14a159657a3f0f6b6a68583fb06ebdf984d70"]

json_data = json.dumps({"data_hash": array_hash})

requests.post(php_url, json=json_data)
```

My Python print array is good, I have this :

```
{  
   "data_hash":[  
      "0x348eb29f3295fedc10b5b869c751fb5479585c7e65169512c3a5ff474bc0e85a",
      "0x63b2590119f7ea533ed93e6b2e6112410fbf49f99157bc6d7e0ce7469d3d23a8",
      "0xfbcdc555a3783b5cfa495ad7a5d14a159657a3f0f6b6a68583fb06ebdf984d70"
   ]
}
```

But now when I'm trying to get it with PHP my array is empty and when I make a loop on the array I have this error :

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Here is my PHP code :

```
if($this->request->isPost()){
    error_log($this->request->getPost('data_hash')[0]);
    foreach ($this->request->getPost('data_hash') as $value) {
        error_log($value);
    }
}
```

But when I send just json string like this :

```
{"test1": "hello", "test2": "world"}
```

I can get it in PHP and it works. So... What is wrong with my Python array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use `data` instead of `json` argument with `headers` argument as well:

```
requests.post(php_url, data=json_data, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json'})
```

Take a look at this in `requests` documentation [More complicated POST requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

In your PHP code you need to use the following: (as your request specifies json for the content type)

```
$rawBody = $this->request->getJsonRawBody(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried to use data but I have the same problem.

Comment: Did you add `headers` and you still have the same issue?

Comment: Yes I have the same issue with the headers :/

Comment: did you test with small hashes in your list?

Comment: When I remove `json.dumps` and headers, `data_hash` is not empty but it contains just the last hash as a string... not an array. I have the same error with a simple array like `['test', 'test2', 'test3']`

Comment: Test with the above headers and let me know if your issue persists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129616/discussion-between-ettanany-and-john).

Comment: `$this->request->getJsonRawBody(true);` fix my problem. Thank you so much !